# Disk Read Error whenever i install XP pro

Tags: windows-xp, raid, sata

I have a computer which has a raid 0 with 2 hard drives

When i installed Vista on the computer it worked fine, saw the raid setup and allowed me to install quickly

But like most people i hated vista so i decided to install XP Pro instead, this involved me having to get a RAID & SATA driver floppy for it to recognise my hard drives

The Install goes fine, but when the computer restarts it always comes up with Disk Read Error

I have used 3 copy's of xp and none of them have worked always comes up with the same error, but when i installed Vista back on it works fine

Comment: Have you re-installed the driver for XP yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try integrating the SATA/RAID drivers directly onto the XP installation disc with [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/).  That way, you won't have to hit F6 to install the drivers from the floppy, but if for whatever reason Windows needs the drivers during the install (e.g. before the first reboot when it is copying the files), it has them.

I know many will be skeptical of this idea, but I highly recommend you give it a shot - it solved a similar problem of mine in the past.

Comment: But how is that different to just loading the drivers using F6

Comment: I tried it last night, used nlite and added the raid sata drivers that were included with the motherboard cd

The same thing happened, installed fine, but on restart comes up with Disk Read Error

Installed Vista and loaded up fine

Comment: What motherboard do you have?  What drivers are you using?

Comment: Asus striker motherboard, im using the drivers that came with the motherboard CD

Comment: to be more specific  - 
Asus Striker Extreme nForce 680 (Socket 775) PCI-Express DDR2 Motherboard

Comment: Have you tried the drivers from http://www.nvidia.com/object/nforce_winxp_15.25.html ?  Download & extract that, and slipstream the SATARAID drivers.

Comment: I'll give that a try tonight, if not i might try dual booting Vista and XP

Comment: Sometimes old Windows XP drivers don't work well with new builds with SP2/SP3, so it might be worth a shot.

Comment: That link didn't work, but i did go onto the nvidia site and download the latest sata raid drivers, nlite the xp installation and it seemed to work, but again the disk read error occured

I got very angry and proceeded to unplug everything except for the raid setup. Restarted and it worked! loaded up fine
This was with no graphics card, i stick of memory etc

I then plugged in everything except 2 300g maxtor drives, so i have the raptor raid setup and a 500gb samsung drive and it again worked!

Comment: This was at 2 in the morning so i left it there, but it seems to be that there was a problem with one of the maxtor drives, i will check on these later