# Installation of Windows XP stuck at "please wait..." with 500g HD

Tags: windows, installation

I just have the computer upgraded to a SATA 500g WD HD, but I'm stuck after this stage:

[image]

After I pressed "ENTER" the computer frozen at "Please wait..." message. No disk or memory operations ever since.

The BIOS recognized the HD by displaying the HD model in POST and the installation disk worked previously. Any ideas?

Comment: I've had the same problem happen to me. The only way I managed to install an OS was to use Vista instead of XP (have no idea why XP didn't work).

Comment: Try my answer here (different question, but it is still relevant!): http://superuser.com/questions/40855/disk-read-error-whenever-i-install-xp-pro/40930#40930

Comment: Is there a Service Pack on this disk you have?

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP does not have built in drivers to recognize SATA drives. You need a floppy disk containing said drivers or slipstream them into the installation media. [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=install+windows+xp+on+sata+drive&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g3) can help you.

If that isn't the issue (i.e. you already have drivers) then it's probably a keyboard issue, as already stateed here, or memory, or the installation media is scratched/broken.

Comment: Do you know which Service Pack this is fixed on? I didn't have a problem with mine, but I was loading SP3.

Comment: SP3, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

it could be that your memory is damaged. If you have spare ones, try them on first.

Comment: Thanks!Will try that. But a warning beep will be heard if the mem is faulty, isn't it?

Comment: No, if memory as a defect, the motherboard will never know. Try http://www.memtest.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Is the keyboard a USB keyboard? That's usually the problem here. Turn on USB compatibility for legacy devices in the BIOS.

Comment: How?  His keyboard works...