# Installation of Windows XP stuck after "to set up windows xp now..." with 500g HD

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I just have the computer upgraded to a SATA 500g WD HD, but I'm stuck after this stage:

[image]

After I pressed "ENTER" the computer frozen at "Please wait..." message. not disk or mem operation ever since.

The BIOS recognized the HD by displaying the HD model in POST and the installation disk worked previously. any clues?

Comment: Duplicate post: http://superuser.com/questions/41406/installation-of-windows-xp-stuck-at-please-wait-with-500g-hd

Answer (score 1):

I would work through the following list first:

Check the

1. Check cd for defects
2. Replace faulty media if step 1 fails
3. Attempt install with no HDD
   connected
4. If hang at the same step, then run Motherboard/Memory diagnostic checks
5. Attempt install with connected HDD if step 3 passes required stage
6. Run HDD tests if problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

Check for known BIOS issues with the mainboard.